# AWS - Changed Permission of All files to ec2-user and wordpress is not uploading or owning any files now

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was not able to upload any files in filezilla.. so i changed permission of all files under /var/www/html to ec2-user

I ran this command - `chown -R ec2-user /var/app/current`

After that Filezilla was working but it burnt the apache.

Now wordpress doesnt create any files in wordpress directory. It says it doesnt have any permission. I guess i killed permission of apache on those files. How can revert back the changes? or atleast how can i give the permissions back as it was?

Answer (score 1):

- Add ec2-user to apache group :
  `sudo usermod -a -G apache ec2-user`

  Logout and Re-login to instance

  - Change the group ownership of /var/www and its contents to the apache group.

  `sudo chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www`

  - To add group write permissions and to set the group ID on future subdirectories, change the directory permissions of /var/www and its subdirectories.

  `sudo chmod 2775 /var/www
  find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} \;`

  - To add group write permissions, recursively change the file permissions of /var/www and its subdirectories:

  `find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} \;`

Pleae Refer to this [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html)

Comment: Hey Glad it worked , please mark the answer as correct so that community can benefit from it.

Comment: I may not have the power to set it as an answer but I up-voted it for you!